# Heavy stones - probability

Tags: probability

There is a box with infinitely many heavy and light stones, the probability pulling an heavy stones is $1/2$, same for the light stone. You pull $n$ stones and build a circle with them.  Let $X_i := \begin{cases}1, \space \text{stone i is heave and stone i+1 is light or vice versa}\\ 0, \space \text{else}\end{cases}$

So far I calculated the expected number of weight changes and determined it to be $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n}X_i\right]= \dfrac{n}{2}$. Now I want to determine $\mathbb{E}[X_i\cdot X_j]$ for $1 \leq i, j \leq n$ in terms of $i$ and $j$ but I'm kind of stuck. I think that $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent and that one then obtains $\mathbb{E}[X_i\cdot X_j] = \mathbb{E}[X_i] \cdot\mathbb{E}[X_j] = \left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right)^2$ but I'm very unsure. Could someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $i=j$ and $n=1$ then
$$
E[x_i^2]=1\cdot 0=0.
$$
If $i=j$ and $n\geq 2$ then
$$
E[X_i^2]=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 0+\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
If $i\neq  j$ and $n=2$ then
$$
E[X_i\cdot X_j]=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 0+\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
If $i\neq j$ and $n\geq 3$ then
$$
E[X_i\cdot X_j]=\frac{3}{4}\cdot 0+\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1=\frac{1}{4}.
$$

Comment: Also, the $X_i$ are pairwise independent for $n\geq 3$ but are not mutually independent. For example if we know $n-1$ of $n$ variables $X_i$ then we can predict the value of the last random variable, since the sum $\sum X_i$ must be even.

Comment: thanks a lot, your comment is what made me a bit thinking since I already knew that it could only be even, so there must be some kind of dependence.